# Integral Evaulation involving exponentials

Tags: integration

Does anyone know how to evaluate the following integral:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{1}^{\infty} 4x^{2} \exp({-2x^{2}})\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation*}
I know how this is done when the lower limit is 0, as this involves the gamma function after a substitution u = $2x^{2}$, but not sure about this case.

Comment: Use the [upper incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: @science how so?

Comment: Just continue what you are doing (the substitution) and compare with the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: @science so I get to:  = $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{2}^{\infty} u^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \exp({-u})  \mathrm{dx}$, what now?

Comment: @science and now i have found this equal to: $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ $\Big[\tfrac{1}{2}\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2},2) + \sqrt{2}\exp({-2})\Big]$. Any suggestions from here?

Comment: That's a closed form in terms of the incomplete gamma function which you can relate to the erf function.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
I= -2 \partial_a \int_1^{\infty} e^{-2 a x^2}dx\big|_{a=1}
$$

and substitute $2ax^2 =y^2$ and get

$$
I= -2 \partial_a \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}} \int_\sqrt{2a}^{\infty} e^{- y^2}dx\right]\Big|_{a=1}
$$

Now apply the [definition of the Error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) to obtain

$$
I= - \partial_a \left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a}}\left[1-\text{Erf}(\sqrt{2a})\right]\right]\Big|_{a=1}
$$

The rest of the excersise is now just a matter of differentiating and setting $a=1$

Comment: it would be nice if you could be helpful and explain why your first step is plausible instead of just writing it

Comment: Because the integrand is integrable and difterentiable we can exchange differentiation and  integration.

Look  for "Feynman's Trick" if you want to learn more about solving integrals with this kind of technique

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$I=\int 4x^{2} \exp({-2x^{2}})\mathrm{d}x$$ First change variable $x=\frac y {\sqrt 2}$ $$I=\sqrt{2}\int y^2 \,e^{-y^2} \mathrm{d}y$$ Integrate by parts $u=y$, $v'=y \,e^{-y^2}$,$u'=1$, $v=-\frac{e^{-y^2}}{2}$. So, $$I=\sqrt{2} \Big(-\frac{1}{2} y\,e^{-y^2} +\int \frac{e^{-y^2}}{2}\mathrm{d}y  \Big)$$ Now, you have a standard integral.

I am sure that you can take from here.